# Rails: In Rails how to use the model’s Attribute API on a tableless model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, attributes, ruby-on-rails-5, activemodel

I have a table-less model like this:

```
class SomeModel
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attribute :foo, :integer, default: 100
end
```

I’m trying to use an attribute from the link below, it works perfectly in normal models however I cannot get it to work in a tableless model.

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Attributes/ClassMethods.html

This causes an undefined

I’ve tried adding active record attributes:

```
include ActiveRecord::Attributes
```

as an include too however this causes a different error related to the schema.

How do I go about using the attribute in a tableless model? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you should be able to do that? I mean, maybe it's not even supported to use that outside an ActiveRecord::Base object.

Comment: Ah that would be a shame, it's got lots of handy features like setting defaults.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to include [`ActiveModel::Attributes`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Attributes/ClassMethods.html)

```
class SomeModel
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Attributes
  attribute :foo, :integer, default: 100
end
```

For some reason its not included in `ActiveModel::Model`. This internal API was extracted out of ActiveRecord in Rails 5 so you can use it with table-less models.

Note that `ActiveModel::Attributes` is **NOT** the same thing as [`ActiveRecord::Attributes`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Attributes/ClassMethods.html). `ActiveRecord::Attributes` is a more specialized implementation that assumes the model is backed by a database schema.

Comment: I tried this, in the original question, it causes an error to do with the schema cache.

Comment: No, you included `ActiveRecord::Attributes` in your question. Thats not the same thing at all although you seem to be confusing the two.  I tested this in Rails 5.2.1 and it works as advertised.

Comment: O thanks, I totally mis-read it, apologies, i'll try this out thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same with `attr_writer`

```
class SomeModel
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_writer :foo

  def foo
    @foo || 100
  end
end
```

Comment: This does not actually achieve the same goal since ActiveRecord::Attributes does quite a bit more than your average accessor such as typecasting.

Comment: You meant since `ActiveModel::Attributes` does quite a bit more than your average accessor such as typecasting and not `ActiveRecord::Attributes` I guess.